# Can’t connect to clients on second router after a while, fixed by reboot

Tags: networking, dhcp, openwrt

I have a wireless bridge in my house and it's openwrt is on 192.168.1.2 (does not have a dhcp server) and uses relayd to connect to 192.168.1.1

I have a Linksys PAP2T ATA adapter (192.168.1.153) connected to the one of the 192.168.1.1 ethernet ports

When both routers are restarted, everything works fine.
After like 20 hours, I can't connect to the PAP2T, and this is what happens when I ping it while being connected to the 192.168.1.2 router

```
Pinging 192.168.1.153 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.2: Destination host unreachable.
```

This problem is fixed when I reboot the bridge router (192.168.1.2)

```
Pinging 192.168.1.153 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.153: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=249
```

does anybody have a clue what might be happening and how a nub like me can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updating firmware. seemed to be a bug with LEDE

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  You can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.